# .NET CCW: WPF form deactivation issue

Tags: c#, wpf, vb6, ccw

I have a hybrid application - VB6 app can invoke some .NET WPF forms via CCW mechanism. These forms process user input (keyboard+mouse) correctly including TAB navigation if they are showed from CCW by method 'ShowDialog'. If I use non-modal method 'Show' I'll get behavior like that: .Net form is deactivated by using navigation keys (TAB, arrow keys) and root VB6 form is activated. Please give me advice how to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Use `ShowDialog`.

Comment: It worked before new requirements appeared. At the beginning we have one way communication. Only VB6 could call .NET. But now we need to implement bi-directional communication by using COM technology: connection points. It allows Callie object (COM) to notify caller by events defined in special interface. If we use ShowDialog method it blocks UI thread for notifications to VB6

Comment: Do you have access to the internals of both applications, i.e. is it your code?

Comment: Yes, it's my code, I can do changes on both sides VB6 and .NET.

Comment: Then why are you talking to a form?  Why not just create a communication channel between the two programs, directly?

Comment: Actually it should be one program at least from user perspective. Com object is inner inproc server. It's temporary solution for incremental replatrorming from VB6 to .NET. There will be no VB code at the end of project and RCW\COM as well. Bi-directional communication is not a aim. Full implementation of two-way communication can cause a mess in the app. But in some cases we want to reuse some parts of VB6 code (from .NET code) instead of replatform them for some reasons.

Comment: These cases are safe because they are last part of invocation chain (they can't call back to .NET or call some other parts that can call .NET code).

Comment: For my purposes I can just use 2nd COM object and use modal windows (ShowDialog), but it may complicate debug. I think I need take a look to windows messages and use some sort of filtration to prevent windows deactivation by clicking navigation keys (Tab, arrows, etc)

Comment: Why don't you just put the VB6 code that you want to repurpose into a COM DLL, and use COM Interop from .NET?

Comment: because the purpose was to save time and don't replatform parts of code that will be deprecated soon. Some integration parts of old app will be resigned in future. It will be completely new code called through some gateway. While we don't have that code, we just call legacy VB6 code from that gateway

Comment: Well, talking to code by automating a UI is the most difficult and most brittle way to do it.  It will take less time (and be more reliable) if you just put the code you need into a DLL and p/invoke it or make it a COM object.  My two cents.

Comment: Thank you for advice. If I don't find how to prevent unsuspected behavior (from my point of view it's not normal to deactivate window by Tab clicking instead of switch on next window control) I will put that code into new COM object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wasn't an issue at all. It's just VB6 related feature (not about .NET or CCW using). Described behavior was due to some forms that contains user controls with default properties such as 'ForwardFocus = false'. If I set the property value to 'true', everything works as expected